# Proof by contradiction to one geometric planar problem

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification

The union of nine planar surfaces, each of area equal to $1$, has a total area equal to $5$. Prove that the overlap of some two of these surfaces has an area greater than or equal to $\frac{1}{9}$.

**My solution:** Suppose by contradiction that the overlap of any of two surfaces has an area $<\frac{1}{9}$.
First surface intersects at most $8$ other surfaces. Then overlap area $<\frac{8}{9}\  (=\frac{8}{9}-\varepsilon_1)$  and blank area $1-(\frac{8}{9}-\varepsilon_1)=\frac{1}{9}+\varepsilon_1 \ (>\frac{1}{9})$

Second surface intersects at most $8$ other surfaces but overlap area $<\frac{8}{9}\  (=\frac{8}{9}-\varepsilon_2)$  and blank area $1-(\frac{8}{9}-\varepsilon_2)=\frac{1}{9}+\varepsilon_2 \ (>\frac{1}{9})$

And the same situation for other surfaces.

Total overlap area is equal to $$(\frac{8}{9}-\varepsilon_1)+(\frac{7}{9}-\varepsilon_2)+\dots +(\frac{1}{9}-\varepsilon_8)=4-\hat{\varepsilon}$$
But blank area in each surface is equal to $\frac{1}{9}+\varepsilon_i$

So the total blank area is equal to $$\sum \limits_{i=1}^{9}\left(\frac{1}{9}+\varepsilon_i\right) =1+\hat{\varepsilon}+\varepsilon_9.$$

So the area of union would be $$4-\hat{\varepsilon}+1+\hat{\varepsilon}+\varepsilon_9=5+\varepsilon_9>5$$
Here we run into contradiction. So our assumption was false.

Is this proof correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is OK.

But you could do it like this. Let $|X|$ means the area of surface $X$.

Say we have surface $S_1,S_2,...S_9$ and suppose that $|S_i\cap S_j|<{1\over 9}$. Since $|S_i|=1$ for each $i$ we have with the principle of inclusion and exclusion:

$$ 5\geq \Big|\bigcup _{i=1}^9 S_i\Big|\geq \sum_{i=1}^9 |S_i|- \sum _{1\leq i\ne j\leq 9} |S_i\cap S_j| > 9-{9\choose 2}\cdot {1\over 9}=5$$
A contradiction.

Comment: Good. What is PIE? And why this inequality is exactly this?

Comment: $$\Big|\bigcup _{i=1}^n S_i\Big|\leq \sum_{i=1}^n |S_i|$$

Comment: $$\Big|\bigcup _{i=1}^n S_i\Big|\geq \sum_{i=1}^n |S_i- \sum _{1\leq i< j\leq n} |S_i\cap S_j||$$

Comment: $$\Big|\bigcup _{i=1}^n S_i\Big|\leq \sum_{i=1}^n |S_i- \sum _{1\leq i< j\leq n} |S_i\cap S_j|+\sum _{1\leq i< j<k\leq n} |S_i\cap S_j\cap S_k|$$

Comment: Could you give a link to the proof of that fact? It would be an interesting to take a look at that.

Comment: Do you see the pattern? Perhaps this could help:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle

Comment: I see the pattern. The sign reverses after adding(substracting).

Comment: Yes, also take a look here: https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Principle_of_Inclusion-Exclusion

Comment: Thanks a lot for links and nice proof. My proof was quite weird ;(

Comment: Actually it was not, it is kind of nature.